# Hypnotic Pattern - Advantage Rolls and Group Attacks

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, advantage-and-disadvantage

A Wizard in my group likes to use Hypnotic Pattern.  It's quite overpowered in its own right, but the way he made it sound is as follows:

Targets that fail are incapacitated and can't move, attack, or react.  So he has the group circle them one at a time, where the entire party gets advantage attack for one round.

I didn't think to question this, but looking deeper, shouldn't it be just a straight attack and after the person is hit, back to regular initiative?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're actually asking? Are you asking whether attacks made against a creature affected by Hypnotic Pattern have Advantage or are you asking something about initiative?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey: I think they're primarily asking the question about advantage and how attacks interact with Hypnotic Pattern, but are presumably unknowingly also under a misconception around initiative. (Though the asker will need to clarify how exactly they think the process interacts with initiative before we can clear up the misconception.)

Answer (score 8):

## No attacks are made with advantage.

[Hypnotic Pattern](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hypnotic-pattern) states:

> On a failed save, the creature becomes charmed for the duration. While charmed by this spell, the creature is incapacitated and has a speed of 0.

The [charmed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Charmed) condition stated:

> - A charmed creature can't attack the charmer or target the charmer with harmful abilities or magical effects.
> - The charmer has advantage on any ability check to interact socially with the creature.

And the [incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated) condition states:

> - An incapacitated creature can't take actions or reactions.

**Neither Hypnotic Pattern, the charmed nor incapacitated conditions grant advantage on attack rolls.**

Hypnotic Pattern also states:

> The spell ends for an affected creature if it takes any damage...

This means that as soon as the first attack hits and deals damage, the spell ends and the affected creature is no longer charmed or incapacitated anyway.

Comment: So it would pick up standard initiative after correct?  Still gives them the advantage of having the first person that goes after the creature while still holding everyone else, right?

Comment: @conf Initiative order is never deviated from in the first place. Each affected creature takes its standard turn but, because it can't do anything, it's effectively skipped. So once the first attack is made (and hits) against a hypnotized creature, that creature would be able to make attacks or shake an ally "out of it" on its turn. But multiple party members may have turns before that happens.

Comment: Further to this, the first successful attack on the target ends the charm effect of the spell. And further again, the spell is not slective - any party members in the area of effect when the mage casts the spell must also make a saving throw or be affected.

Comment: @ConfusedDM if you have a question about Hypnotic Pattern and initiative then I would suggest asking that as a seperate post.

Comment: @ConfusedDM or if *this* question is actually suppose to be asking about initiative then please clarify that. It's not actually clear what you're trying to ask.